# Firebase Messaging (for notifications) alternatives for Flutter Windows Platform

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-windows

I am working on compiling the existing flutter code which works currently on Android and iOS to be compatible with Windows Platform, but using Firebase in its core, and it is not supported officially for windows platform as of now (specifically the services which we are using - firebase_messaging, firebase_crashlytics), facing some challenges.

I am trying to implement the following answer [using firedart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74959359/22220883) but again when the app is killed not able to get the data(works fine in background and foreground). Help will be highly appreciated!!! Thanks